# A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, methods, types

hello when i use this generic method i get this error

> A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'T'.

what the error here

```dart
sums<T extends num>(List<T> list) {
  T res =list[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
   res = res + list[i];
  }
  print(res);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to either be a bug or a misunderstood feature of Dart 2.12+. In either case, it might be worth opening an issue on the Dart Github page.

If I run the following code in 2.12.0:

```dart
void main() {
  final nums = [1, 2.0, 3.5];
  final ints = [1, 2, 3];
  final doubles = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3];
  
  sums(nums);
  sums(ints);
  sums(doubles);
}

void sums<T extends num>(List<T> list) {
  T res = list[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    res = res + list[i];
  }

  print(res);
}
```

I get the error you mentioned:

```
main.dart:14:9: Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'.
    res = res + list[i];
              ^
```

If, however, I run the same code in Dart 2.10.5, the program compiles and runs without a problem and I get the following printout:

```
6.5
6
6.6
```

My best guess is that there is an issue with type inference where the type parameter of the `List` is concerned. Instead of taking the actual type parameter passed to `sums`, it seems instead to be taking the type restraint `num` as its inferred type. As a result, the type system sees that you are adding a `num` to a `T extends num` and then assigning it to the latter. (To explain, imagine `T` is `int`. A `num` plus an `int` would result in a `num`. Trying to then assign that to an `int` results in a type error since, for all the type system knows, the `num` might actually be a `double`.)

At any rate, the error goes away once you do what the error suggests and cast the elements of `list` to `T`:

```dart
void sums<T extends num>(List<T> list) {
  T res = list[0] as T;
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    res = res + list[i] as T;
  }

  print(res);
}

// Prints:
//
// 6.5
// 6
// 6.6
```

Interestingly, though, using an addition-assignment instead will cause the same error regardless of the cast:

```dart
void sums<T extends num>(List<T> list) {
  T res = list[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    res += list[i] as T;
  }

  print(res);
}

// Prints:
//
// main.dart:14:9: Error: A value of type 'num' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'.
//     res += list[i];
//         ^
```

---

EDIT: [I've filed an issue for this topic on the Dart SDK Github page.](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45400)

---

EDIT 2: Turns out this is not a bug but the result of an intended change to Dart as part of 2.12. See Irn's answer for details.

Comment: yes , you are right !!! this issue was not found in previews version and hope that dart solve it .thank you so much your answer was helpful and solve it.

Answer (score 15):

The issue here is that Dart's new Null Safety feature, introduced in Dart 2.12.0, removed *implicit downcasts* from the language.

If `res` has type `T` where `T extends num`, then the operation `res + something` has static type *num*. The only thing we know about `T` is that it implements `num`, and `num.operator+` returns `num`.
However, `num` is not assignable to `T extends num` because the latter is a subtype of the former (`T` could be `int`, not all `num` values are assignable to `int`).
So, you need an *explicit cast* to make the assignment valid:

```dart
res = (res + list[i]) as T;
```

is such a cast. If you just write `res = res + list[i] as T;`, the precedence of `as` means that it's the same as the cast above.
In Dart 2.10.x, it worked without the explicit cast because the language inserted an *implicit* cast for you.

If you write `res += list[i] as T;` it instead means `res = res + (list[i] as T);` which is an unnecessary cast since `list[i]` already has type `T`, and doesn't cast the result of the addition.

The reason this doesn't fail all the time for `int res = ...; res = res + otherInt;` is that the language specification treats `int.operator+` specially (along with some similar integer operators) and recognizes when the result is an integer, even if the `+` operator's return type is `num`. That special-casing does not apply to `T extends num`.